# Template-less Django + AJAX: Does Django's CSRF token get updated during the course of a browsing session?

Tags: ajax, django, csrf, django-csrf

My current setup is AngularJS + Django 1.5 and I have completely thrown away the use of Django's template engine (ie. the backend is pretty much an API server).

Since I am not using the `csrf_token` template tag, Django, in turn, does not set and send the `csrftoken` cookie in response. As instructed by the official docs, the `ensure_csrf_cookie()` decorator should be used to force the decorated view to send the `csrftoken` cookie.

I have applied the `ensure_csrf_cookie()` decorator to the view, which serves the first GET request that my web client calls at bootstrapping. With that, my web client gets a hold of the CSRF token and henceforth is allowed to call unsafe methods (ex. POST) to the server.

The above setup works fine only if the CSRF token remains the same until the browsing session ends.

**Question:** Does Django's CSRF token get updated during the course of a browsing session? If 'yes', does that mean I would need to apply the `ensure_csrf_cookie()` decorator to all the views I have?

Comment: 1) not likely, but IMHO it is an implementation detail and I advice against relying on this behavior. 2) Just write a Mixin or a View base class decorated by `ensure_csrf_cookie()` and use it as the base for your API view (probably there is a lot of boilerplate code you can move there as well).

Comment: Thx @PauloScardine. I agree with what you said. Would there be any security implications if the csrf token cookie is set for all server responses?

Comment: AFAIK there is no security implication and frameworks like Django-REST-Framework do this - in fact you should consider it in the next project since it buys you things like pagination, throttling and a fancy permission system.

Comment: @PauloScardine - LOL. I am using Django REST Framework for the current project. I love it. But I don't see that the rest_framework is forcing CSRF cookie in its base view (ie. APIView) nor any of its generic views. Am I missing something? Note that I have rest_framework v2.3.8.

Comment: Do you have session-based authentication on?

Comment: @PauloScardine - Yes, 'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication' is the only authentication scheme configured for my project.

Comment: I have the same setup and it works for me by default (csrf token cookie is sent with every request), so I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: @PauloScardine - Does your API server serve HTML response, including BrowsableAPI, by any chance? By looking at the django source, it seems to be that the csrf cookie is automatically included only when `RequestContext` is used. My API server serves only JSON, so that explains why I have to manually force the inclusion of the cookie.

Comment: bingo; I serve the app HTML from django, so the session cookies are there when Angular bootstraps.

Comment: @PauloScardine - Mystery solved! It had been bugging my head. Thx for your responses. Post your original comment as an answer. I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1) Does Django's CSRF token get updated during the course of a browsing session?

Looks like the [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29) token is unique per session, but it is based in my observations, I have no "official" source. With Angular.js I use the following code without problems:

```
angular.module('app', ...)
  .config(function($httpProvider) {
    var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
    var csrftoken = _.find(cookies, function(v) { 
                      return v.trim().indexOf('csrftoken=') == 0; 
                    });
    if(csrftoken) {
      $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRFToken'] = csrftoken.split('=')[1];
    }
  })
```

Since I serve the HTML from Django, by the time Angular bootstraps the cookie is already there.

> 2) If 'yes', does that mean I would need to apply the ensure_csrf_cookie() decorator to all the views I have?

You can try [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) instead if [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29). [Otto Yiu](https://github.com/ottoyiu/) maintains the [django-cors-headers](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers/) package, which is known to work correctly with REST framework APIs.

Some (untested) ideas to apply `ensure_csrf_cookie()`:

- monkey-patch APIView
- create a CSRFCookie mixin and add it to your views
- apply `ensure_csrf_cookie()` to your base classes

Answer (score 1):

Giving support to the @Paulo Scardine ideas of applying the `ensure_csrf_cookie()` (which I consider valid, and useful), I would like to add a new one possible solution to it, if you definitely have to `ensure_csrf_cookie()` in all your views. You could write a custom `middleware`, and implement the logic that is there inside the `ensure_csrf_cookie`. Something like this:

On your `app.middleware.py`:

```
from django.middleware.csrf import get_token


class EnsureCsrfCookie(object):

    def process_request(self, request):
        # Forces process_response to send the cookie
        get_token(request)
```

and of courses on your `settings` file add the middleware to the `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    .,
    .,
    .,
    'app.middleware.EnsureCsrfCookie',
    .,
    .,
    .,
)
```

It is just one idea more to face this problem. I hope it can be useful for somebody in the future.